# Android studio error rise :app:processDebugManifest while play-services-ads:8.1.0 added on build gradle

Tags: java, android, xml, build.gradle

Hi I am developing an android application. Most the functionality already implemented and working fine. Now I trying to integrate add to google AdMob ads.

But while I add google add services on dependencies section of build.gradle file my application stopped working with error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

My build.gradle file configuration as follow:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.coder.reports"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
}
```

Please let know me what I exactly missing or what's wrong with my config file?

Comment: Do u have any jars in your lib folder. And post your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution of your error:**

In your **build.gradle** you have used play-services-ads version is 8.1.0 and **minSdkVersion** is 8 which is smaller then that 8.1.0 that's why you are getting error.

Based on your case you can not set **minSdkVersion** smaller then **9**. Just update your default section as follow and then sync hopefully your issue will be resolved

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.coder.reports"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Your are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

please update the minSdkVersion to 8 to 16 in your manifest file:-

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.coder.reports"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```